# How to scrape time tag using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the date of the tweet using the following code

```
div_class="css-901oao r-18jsvk2 r-37j5jr r-a023e6 r-16dba41 r-rjixqe r-bcqeeo r-bnwqim r-qvutc0    
page = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
        contents = soup.find_all(class_=div_class)
           
        for p in contents:
            print(p.time)
```

but **None** is printed

Comment: On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, take a look [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. Question could be improved by further details (HTML, url, expected result) to clarify and formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that the element is included in your `soup` - Classes look high dynamic so better change your selection strategy and use more static id, HTML structure, attriutes.

Following [`css selector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) selects all `<time>` that is an directly child of an `<a>`:

```
for t in soup.select('a>time'):
    # tag / element 
    print(t)

    # text
    print(t.text)

    # attribute value
    print(t.get('datetime))
```

Comment: Thank you @HedgeHog 
I want to get the text from 
div_class="css-901oao r-18jsvk2 r-37j5jr r-a023e6 r-16dba41 r-rjixqe r-bcqeeo r-bnwqim r-qvutc0    

and the corresponding time from the 'a' class